# How to add a custom build step with qmake without re-making all targets?

Tags: qt, qmake

Here's a simple example of adding a custom build step:

```
mytarget.commands = @echo Testing123
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget
PRE_TARGETDEPS += mytarget
```

This works, and prints the message as expected. However, it also re-makes all targets in my project every time I build, which takes minutes.

If I take out `PRE_TARGETDEPS += mytarget`, no message is printed and the build succeeds quickly with no changes. But I need the message to print.

I need a pre-build step to execute, but I don't want any other targets to be remade if their dependencies didn't change. How can I achieve this with qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a file on disk to make it working:

```
PRETARGET = .pretarget

!exists($$OUT_PWD/$$PRETARGET):system(touch $$OUT_PWD/$$PRETARGET)
$${PRETARGET}.depends = FORCE # or $${PRETARGET}.CONFIG = phony
$${PRETARGET}.commands = @echo -e \"[\\e[1m\\e[32mTARGET\\e[0m] $$OUT_PWD/$(DESTDIR_TARGET)\"
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += $$PRETARGET
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PRETARGET
```

Comment: You are a life saver! The only change I had to make was to remove @ from @touch. And the echo is wonky. But it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Steve Removed the extra @. By some reason it works on Windows. The echo is for an example only.

Comment: The echo issues are probably OS dependent differences again. Escape characters probably work differently. I was testing on Mac.